# Mathematica vs Rubi --- integrate $f(x,y) = x \sin^2 x + a x y$ --- Mathematica got this round?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, trigonometry, rubi

Consider the function:

$$
\begin{equation}
f(x,y) = x \sin^2 x + a x y
\end{equation}
$$

with $a$ being a constant.

We want to do the indefinite integral over $x$ and then over $y$. We do that using `Rubi` and without it.

```
$Version
Get["Rubi`"]
$RubiVersion
```

> `"12.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)"`

> `"Rubi 4.16.1.0"`

We have

```
f[x_, y_] := x Sin[x]^2 + a x y

mma1 = Integrate[f[x, y], x] // Expand
mma2 = Integrate[mma1, y] // Expand
```

> `x^2/4 + 1/2 a x^2 y - 1/8 Cos[2 x] - 1/4 x Sin[2 x]`

> `(x^2 y)/4 + 1/4 a x^2 y^2 - 1/8 y Cos[2 x] - 1/4 x y Sin[2 x]`

Also

```
rubi1 = Int[f[x, y], x] // TrigReduce // Expand
rubi2 = Int[rubi1, y] // TrigReduce // Expand
```

> `1/8 + x^2/4 + 1/2 a x^2 y - 1/8 Cos[2 x] - 1/4 x Sin[2 x]`

> `y/8 + (x^2 y)/4 + 1/4 a x^2 y^2 - 1/8 y Cos[2 x] - 1/4 x y Sin[2 x]`

And in case it is not obvious from the presentation above:

```
mma1 - rubi1 // TrigReduce
mma2 - rubi2 // TrigReduce
```

> `-(1/8)`

> `-(y/8)`

Doing the computation by hand - prime is derivative w.r.t the variable under the integral sign:

$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\int dx ~ (x \sin^2 x + a x y) &= \int dx ~ x \sin^2 x + \int dx ~ a x y \\
&= \int dx ~ x ~ \left(\frac{x}{2} - \frac{1}{4} \sin (2 x) \right)^{\prime} + a y \frac{x^2}{2} \\
&= x ~ \left(\frac{x}{2} - \frac{1}{4} \sin (2 x) \right) - \int dx ~ x^{\prime} ~ \left(\frac{x}{2} - \frac{1}{4} \sin (2 x) \right) + a y \frac{x^2}{2} \\
&= x ~ \left(\frac{x}{2} - \frac{1}{4} \sin (2 x) \right) - \int dx ~ \left(\frac{x}{2} - \frac{1}{4} \sin (2 x) \right) + a y \frac{x^2}{2} \\
&= x ~ \left(\frac{x}{2} - \frac{1}{4} \sin (2 x) \right) - \int dx ~ \frac{x}{2} + \int \frac{1}{4} \sin (2 x) + a y \frac{x^2}{2} \\
&= \frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{x}{4} \sin(2x) - \frac{x^2}{4} - \frac{1}{8} \cos(2x) + a y \frac{x^2}{2} \\
&= \frac{x^2}{4} + \frac{1}{2} a x^2 y - \frac{x}{4} \sin(2x) - \frac{1}{8} \cos(2x)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
$$

which agrees with `Mathematica` and not `Rubi`.

To pinpoint what is going wrong, I tried to make `Rubi` show what she did by using `Steps`

```
Steps[Int[f[x, y], x]]
```

[image: rubi]

and now it's quite obvious -first is the `Rubi` result and the second comes form `Mathematica`

```
-(1/2) x Cos[x] Sin[x] + Sin[x]^2/4 // TrigExpand
-(1/8) Cos[2 x] - 1/4 x Sin[2 x] // TrigExpand
```

> `1/8 - Cos[x]^2/8 - 1/2 x Cos[x] Sin[x] + Sin[x]^2/8`

> `-(1/8) Cos[x]^2 - 1/2 x Cos[x] Sin[x] + Sin[x]^2/8`

I tried to look online if there are any conflicts of `Rubi` with Linux or `V12`, but have not found anything. Also, in other examples I tried there is agreement; i.e `f[x_, y_] := a x + b y` for a very simple one and something closer to what I presented above `f[x_, y_] := x Sin[x] + a x y`.

Is this something that has to be reported to the `Rubi` team? Am I missing something so obvious?

Finally, I am attaching a screenshot for the example `x Sin[x] + a x y`

[image: screenrubi]

Comment: Better compute definite integrals.

Comment: @yarchik Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question about Mathematica but rather it's about Rubi. Also it does not seem to account for constants of integration (which again is not an issue of Mathematica but rather of the underlying math).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I was under the impression that since we already have a tag called `Rubi` this would also be the place to pose some questions. My bad

Comment: You asked for the elaboration of my comment. What I am saying, a correct way to compare two integrations is to compare the values of integrals along a path (definite integrals) rather than antiderivatives (indefinite integrals). The latter has some freedom as @Nasser explains.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why it happened:

When you integrate `Int[f[x, y], x]` Rubi's answer is correct. But it generates an extra constant `1/8`. This is valid, since anti-derivatives that differ by only a constant are both correct.

When you integrate this result again now, this constant will generate the extra term now you see in the final result.  If you "remove" this constant first before doing the second integration, then both now give same result. This is done below "by hand" but this could be automated ofcourse by removing terms that do not depend on `x` or `y` using `FreeQ`.

```
rubi1 = Int[f[x, y], x] // TrigReduce // Expand
Simplify[D[rubi1, x] - f[x, y]]
(* 0 *)
```

Which shows the first integration is correct. Now remove the extra constant before doing the second integration

```
rubi1 = rubi1 - 1/8
rubi2 = Int[rubi1, y]
mma1 = Integrate[f[x, y], x]
mma2 = Integrate[mma1, y]
Simplify[rubi2 - mma2]

(* 0 *)
```

Comment: Thanks for this reply. I know that it was the initial $1/8$ constant that caused the second disagreement, and that's why I presented everything in the way I did. Perhaps I should have been more explicit about this. It's just still not clear why `Rubi` generated this extra constant term in the first integration.

Comment: @kcr Rubi uses build in "Rules" to do the integration. Mathenatica probably uses different methods/algorithm for integration. The side effect of this is that Rubi generated an extra constant due to the way its rules worked in this specific case. Both are correct anti-derivatives but need to be careful and remove the constant before integrating again.

Comment: Thanks for that. The answer is already upvoted by me and I am going to accept your answer after this comment, just so you know, but since this is the basic explanation of the situation perhaps you'd like to move it to your main response.